# Unsupported span of 4.3m as a mezzanine floor - what size timber and how to attach it to the walls at either side?

Tags: floor, joists, structural, timber-framing

I'm building an internal mezzanine floor in a tall and wide room.  The room is 4.3m wide and the mezzanine floor will cover half the room area - so there will be a beam that goes from one wall to the other, which will support the joists that come out from the walls.  I'm hoping to not support this beam across the room, so its an unsupported 4.3m stretch.

I appreciate that I need some structural engineering knowledge here - is there a table or charts that contain info like this?  Or is there a site that has this info? I'm also hoping to just attach the beam directly to the wall - any tips on how to safely do this with enough strength also really appreciated!

Update: The floor size of the mezzanine will be 2.6m x 4.3m.  So the open span is 4.3m from wall to wall.  The joists will go from the back wall to the beam, a distance of 2.6m. I'm planning on fixing the whole thing to the walls.

Comment: The length and width of the floor is needed.  Span of floor from supports to beam.  Not sure if open span is 2.2m or 4.3m.

Comment: First - you should probably get a structural engineer to confirm anything you come up with.

Second - what kind of wood? and what design load? Reference tables for this all need to know the load and lumber type.

Comment: thanks @crip659 and KMJ - have added measurements above

Comment: Re Lumber, Im in the UK - joists are made of standard C24 kiln dried timber (I think thats a uk expression).  Theres no options for the wood material - its just flooring joists.  Options are for size: from 4x2 (47mmx100mm) to 9x3 (75mmx224mm).  Im imagining I'll need the big ones, 2x - screwed together.

Comment: Will this 4.3m beam be "attached" to the wall, or will you be opening the wall up and building support posts that the ends will sit on? I honestly cannot imagine any sort of joist/beam hanger that would meet code here in the US to support it "attached to the wall".

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for q, i wasnt sure whether i could fix the beam to the wall or not.  Ive been trying to find this out.  I might have to create vertical columns to support the ends of the beam.

Comment: Am wondering whether instead I should go into the wall, remove some bricks and sit the beam into the wall.

Comment: A _lot_ is going to depend on where in the structure the wall is and what kind of footing it has underneath it. You're _really_ going to need a structural engineer to look at any plan you may come up with. It'll cost you, but it'll cost a lot less than a collapse and/or long term damage to the house.

Comment: This is a huge old brick art college. I’m on the second floor and each floor is 5m high. The walls are 3 brick layers thick, it’s built like a fort and indestructible.